# grabbing variables from 1 class and using them in another without inheritance c#

Tags: c#, class, variables

I'm making a chess game and for the pieces to move I need the variable `board` and it's located in the `Form1` class. I was wondering if there is anyway to call the `board` variable in my base class so I can use it in my other classes that reference my base class.

This is how code looks (I only included key parts not everything)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string[,] board = new string[8, 8];
}

class Pieces
{
   //I want there to be a variable here that will always contain the exact data as the board variable
   //I also have other variables that are in the Form1 class that I need in here
}

class Rook : Pieces
{
   //This is just a small sample of how I set up the moves but its in a for loop
   if (board[x + i, y] == null && !board[x + i, y].Contains("King"))
         pieceMove.AddLast(placementBoard[x + i, y]);
}
```

This is what I've thought of but I want to know if there is a different approach

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string[,] board = new string[8, 8];
    Rook[] whiteRook = new Rook[10];//I made an array of rooks so when a pawn gets to the opposite side of the board it can turn into a rook


    public Form1()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         Rook[0] whiteRook = new Rook();
         whiteRook.board = board;//Everytime a piece moves I will call this with every piece to update it
    }
}

class Pieces
{
   public string[,] board = new string[8,8];
}

class Rook : Pieces
{
   //This is just a small sample of how I set up the moves but its in a for loop
   if (board[x + i, y] == null && !board[x + i, y].Contains("King"))
         pieceMove.AddLast(placementBoard[x + i, y]);
}
```

Comment: First of all try creating class PIECES a friend class of FORM1 that way you will have access of all variables of form1 in pieces. But the board is public so I will assume you want just a single instance of board so why dont make it static. But if you dont want to do that then what you can do is create a function in pieces class that receives a form1 object and since board is public it will be readily available in that functon through that object. Apart from this as BradleyDOTNET said you should consider changing your object model.

Comment: I am fairly new to programming so I really don't understand what static does or how to effectively use classes, I know this is a bad habit but I've been really avoiding using classes in that program, I really just hard coded all the moves and everything in the `Form1` class but i put the board variable to public to try and see if I can access it from the pieces class and just couldn't be asked to remove it. Right now I have it as `public static string[,] board = new string[8,8]; and I copied the movement for the rook and put it in the rook class and it doesn't want to move now

Comment: I fixed it so now the rook moves, it was because of a null reference exception inside of an if statement

Comment: Note that you should use `static` *carefully*; because you have created a global you can get unexpected effects if multiple objects/threads interact with it. Its a good tool, but you need to know how to use it and what side-effects there are.

Comment: I've never used the `static` code at all and the way I see it is a key word that will change that one variable for the whole class instead of the individual class. So am i using it right?

Comment: Yes that is what static *does* (the variable is shared between instances of the class, or methods are accessible without an instance). Just beware that the repercussions of doing this can cause you some very hard to track bugs (mostly in large complex systems, not a programming assignment, but you don't want bad habits :) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefer composition over inheritance.

Your object model is all wrong right now. You are trying to control *everything* from the various piece classes when those should just contain piece specific logic, the containing class should control the state. You really want to have a `Board` object that *contains* `Piece` objects that you can then subclass

```
public class Board
{
    List<Piece> pieces;
}

public abstract class Piece
{
     //Some base behavior/interface
     public bool Move(int xTarget, int yTarget)
     {
         if (IsValidMove(xTarget, yTarget))
         {
            //Do stuff
         }
     }

     protected abstract bool IsValidMove(int xTarget, int yTarget);
}
```

And then subclass `Rook`, `Bishop` etc from "Piece". If necessary you can pass the `Board` into the `Piece` via constructor or a property but that dependency is very much the wrong way, the `Board` should be controlling its own state.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that advanced to I don't really know how that works

Comment: Or really what you mean  by subclass and everything

Comment: @DoomedSpace Could you be a bit more specific? You already created a subclass in your attempt by writing `Rook : Pieces` I'm trying to put the beginnings of a correct OO design in my answer without writing the whole thing, so to help more I'll need a more specific question. Do you understand inheritance? Polymorphism? Do you just need "subclass" defined (if so, its just a class that derives from another)

Comment: I had an array named `board` which contained where the all the pieces where on the board, it was in the default class names `Form1`. I wanted to know how I could access and change the values in `board` from another class. I didn't want to inherit all the variables in the `Form1` class I just wanted that specific variable. I found out that using the keyword static helped me achieve this purpose but you said to be careful when I use that keyword because of the "side effects". I hope this was a bit more specific

Comment: @DoomedSpace Right, my basic answer is *that's the wrong approach*. If you treat your pieces as real objects then they would *never* mutate the board state directly. The board would ask them applicable questions and mutate its own state accordingly. Apart from side-effects; using `static` here is just going to teach you bad habits regarding global state (which you should pretty much never have outside an IoC container, and you clearly aren't ready for that concept yet)

Comment: Yeah this probably was too big of a project to handle, I've really only taken  1 year of computer programming in high school and right now I'm taking my second year. Also what's an IoC container?

Comment: @DoomedSpace IoC = Inversion of Control; its a way to do dependency injection. But to understand dependency injection you really need to understand polymorphism and inheritance, and it doesn't seem like you are there yet. High school programming classes rarely teach the right way to program unfortunately.

Comment: Well I just learned a lot from trial and error working with code in my spare time but theres only so much one can do

Comment: @DoomedSpace Understood, and I'm happy to help :) If you have a specific question I'm more than happy to answer it.

Comment: I just realized what you said (I think), you said that the pieces would _never_ mutate the board state directly (Which means the pieces would never change whats on the board correct?) But that's not what I did (I think) I have a list that records all the spaces that the piece can move inside of their class, I declared it in the `Form1` class and it just holds the moves and I have a loop that will enable those buttons located in the `Form1` class. Idk if this is still the same thing as the pieces mutating the board but thats how I have it set up. (Sorry if I confused you)

Comment: @DoomedSpace I think you are close, the primary thing is that a piece doesn't say `Board.Location[2,1] = this` (mutating means changing state) or something like that. SO isn't really a good format to explain how to design a game like chess, but the game isn't terribly hard to model/create. In your example, I would probably have a function on `Piece` that takes the pieces position (or a piece could hold its current position as state) and returns all possible moves. Then the board class could remove any illegal moves (such as those that require moving past another piece).

Comment: I do have that, for the rook i have a function called `moves` and it grabs the piece's `x` and `y` and then it will run a for loop until it it hits a piece or the index goes out of bounds and it just puts all those moves in a list then i run a foreach loop to disable all the buttons that aren't in the list and enable all the ones that are

Comment: @DoomedSpace I think the piece you are missing is that the piece shouldn't enable/disable button. It should just return a list and let "higher level" classes take care of the edge conditions and enable/disable. Overall you are on the right track though.

Comment: Piece doesn't enable/enable the button it does have a static list that i clear everytime a new piece is clicked on, I enable/disable the buttons in the `Form1`

Comment: @DoomedSpace So you are definitely on the right track then (a static list means *something* is wrong but it probably isn't important :) ). Good luck, and don't be afraid to ask again if you run into something.

Comment: Thanks man and I will surely ask if I run into another problem